# Get Businesses connectivity field Value in NewForm.aspx with Jquery

Tags: jquery

how can i get the Businesses connectivity field Value  in NewForm.aspx with Jquery.
i tried with this script:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff4{$Pos}" ControlMode="New"   FieldName="Action" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff4',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Action')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff4description{$Pos}" FieldName="Action" ControlMode="New"/>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                                   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                                  $(&quot;textarea[id*=&apos;_ff4_&apos;]&quot;).change( function((){
             alert( $(&quot;textarea[id*=&apos;_ff4_&apos;]&quot;).val() );
                               });

          )};
    </script>
```

but no luck,

Any help will be appreciated ,

Thanks,

Omri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the form in a browser after it has rendered.  If you are using IE then press F12 and you should be able to see the HTML layout that is generated and amend your jQuery accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, i tried that and the filed name was "ctl00_m_g_ec2f2b05_31d0_4b2e_895f_9a85560937c2_ff4_1_ctl00_5a73a1b2_1c9c_4611_8887_a71faa434a2d_Picker" but again no luck. i tried to add title but this kind of field can't use this property. need more ideas.... Omri

Comment: What sort of field is it?  I can see it says picker - so is that a select?  If so then I think you need to make sure you get the selected option.

Comment: it is business connectivity field (external data.)  i tried it and nothing. the thing is to get the control. in other fields i can add title property and work with it but here i can't. Omri

Comment: You do not need to add a title property - just need to grab one that is there which you can use.  But you need to get it after the page has rendered as you will have noticed that it looks different.  That said, I have not tried it with BCS so I guess it is possible it has been locked down in some way.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply i'll try it. do you know the name of the event that will fire the  after BCS is chosen? so i can take the value, "selected" , "change" didn't work. there probably something else i 'm not aware of. Thanks, Omri

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: hi manage it to work  by using this code as you suggested:   var note = $(&quot;textarea[id*=&apos;ff4_&apos;]&quot;);  but now i'm finding problem to get the value. it gives all html tag instead of just the value of the field.